# How to escape SELECT COUNT (*) and create a table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am fairly new to working with PHP and WordPress. I tried exploring how to escape and sanitize, and I got a little confused along the way.

I'd like to echo out the contents of an entire table from the database. I am unsure whether there is a better way of both creating a table in a more structured way, and I can't figure out how to escape the data when I don't select specific data from the database. Maybe i'm just confused. Any help or pointers is highly appreciated.

I found the code somewhere on Stack Overflow, edited a little and tried to understand it. I understand it now, but I am still confused on where to go from here.

```
    <?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM user"); // Query to fetch data from database table and storing in $results
if(!empty($results))                        // Checking if $results have some values or not
{
    echo "<table width='100%' border='0' id='userTable'>"; // Adding <table> and <tbody> tag outside foreach loop so that it wont create again and again
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";                           // Adding rows of table inside foreach loop
    echo "<th>E-mail</th>"  . "<th>Fornavn</th>" . "<th>Efternavn</th>" . "<th>Registreret den</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($results as $row){              //putting the user_ip field value in variable to use it later in update query
    echo "<td colspan='3'><hr size='2'></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . esc_attr($row->email) . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row->firstname . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row->signuptime . "</td>";   //fetching data from user_ip field
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";

}

?>
```

Comment: in your foreach loop, you directly echo a <td> without a enclose it with <tr>

Answer (score 0):

This part...

```
foreach($results as $row){              
    //putting the user_ip field value in variable to use it later in update query
    echo "<td colspan='3'><hr size='2'></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . esc_attr($row->email) . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row->firstname . "</td>" 
    . "<td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row->signuptime . "</td>";   
   //fetching data from user_ip field
}
```

...would product html like

```
{3 columns}{content}{3 columns end}{row start}
{column start}{content}{column end} * 4

{3 columns}{row start}
{column start}{content}{column end} * 4

{3 columns}{row start}
{column start}{content}{column end} * 4
```

etc

**What you want in your loop is probably:**

```
{row start}{4 columns}{content}{4 columns end}{row end}
{row start}{column start}{content}{column end} * 4{row end}
```

which would look like this:

```
foreach($results as $row){              
    //putting the user_ip field value in variable to use it later in update query
    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'><hr size='2'></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>" . esc_attr($row->email) . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row->firstname . " 
    </td><td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row->signuptime . "</td></tr>";   
   //fetching data from user_ip field
}
```

In your SQL-statement on your first row: `SELECT * FROM user` , **all fields are returned** into the `$results` array of objects.  If you want to specify which fields are returned you simply include them **instead** of the *, e.g. `SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname FROM user`

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I do want to select all of the fields. Do I still have to escape the data? 

It's all still a bit messy in my head. Your answer definitely clarified some stuff, though.

Comment: When you're fetching the data as your doing in your example, I don't think it's necessary to escape it all. The data should be secured/validated when inserted in the database. This is a good resource for this: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that escaping is unnecessary when the data has already been sanitized when it was input in the database?

Comment: That is my opinion yes.. If not sanitized when "incorrect data" is in the database, then the harm is already done.